# How to use key listener for macro actions

Tags: java

I am trying to do something that move according to keyboard press: if uparrow is pressed go up etc.

My problem is that I dont know how to capture multiple key presses.

For example, if uparrow and leftarrow are pressed together I want to go upleft.

That what I did so far:

```
shell.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN)
            setUserCommand(2);
        else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP)
            setUserCommand(8);
        else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT)
            setUserCommand(4);
        else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT)
            setUserCommand(6);
}
});
```

How can I capture multiple key presses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an abstraction of a key pressed, perhaps just a boolean that keeps track of it, and test that at some relevant okay time (perhaps in the `keyPressed` method, or perhaps in some `checkKeysThatArePressedMethod` that you create which is called at sometime in your game loop (if that's what you have).

```
boolean upPressed = false;
boolean downPressed = false;
...
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN){
        downPressed = true;
        if (upPressed){
            // both are pressed here
        } 
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP){
        upPressed = true;
        if (downPressed){
            // both are pressed here
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN)
        downPressed = false;
    else if(e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP)
        upPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer your looking for.

Comment: I don't undrstand how this works. can you please explain this for me.

Comment: Keep track of what keys are pressed, keep track when they get released. At the appropriate time, check if any combination of keys are pressed. What specifically do not understand because this is pretty much a copy paste of the code you have while adding a boolean variable to the mix.